# Joomla deployments on multiple webservers

Tags: joomla, amazon-web-services, webserver

Hi we have a Joomla app running in AWS. One DB with multiple webservers. How do we roll out updates done via CMS? When we get to auto-scaling how to we guarantee to get latest code?

We have SVN for other sites but with CMS changes are made outside SVN. We are trying using NFS but that just adds another unneeded layer.